# Sed error when substituting pattern with variable

Tags: shell, variables, sed

I have a problem with "sed" command in Shell Script,

I have the following script to try and replace 3 "labels" with information that I capture from 2 other files:

```
#!/bin/sh

VAR1=$(cat file1.sh | grep --max-count=1 DLC=)
VAR2=$(cat file1.sh | grep --max-count=1 PROPATH=)
VAR3=$(cat file2.sh | grep -e - )

sed 's|PATTERN1|'"$VAR1"'|' < Template.sh > temp1.sh
sed 's|PATTERN2|'"$VAR2"'|' < temp1.sh > temp2.sh
sed 's|PROGRESS_CONNECTION|'"$VAR3"'|' < temp2.sh > Final.sh
```

Note that the contents of the 3 vars are strings like (without the double quotes):

```
VAR1="DLC=/user/aaa/bbb;export DLC"
VAR2="PROPATH=/user/ccc/ddd;export PROPATH"
VAR3="-db docdb -trig triggers -H sona01 -S 19001 -N TCP -ld newyork 
      -db docadm -trig triggers -H sona01 -S 19002 -N TCP -ld docadm 
      -db dochelp -trig triggers -H sona01 -S 19003 -N TCP -ld dochelp 
      -yy 1920 -rereadnolock -T /tmp -c 30 -d mdy -Bt 350 -D 100 -mmax 8192 -nb 200 -s 160 -noshvarfix -inp 32000 
      -cpinternal utf-8 -cpstream utf-8 -cpcoll ICU-UCA"
```

When I run this script, temp1.sh is correctly created, temp2.sh is correctly created, but Final.sh is not created and I get a sed error message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 91: unterminated `s' command
```

At this point I am unsure of what is causing the problem.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `$VAR3` variable does contain some newline characters.

```
$ echo "$VAR3"
-db docdb -trig triggers -H sona01 -S 19001 -N TCP -ld newyork 
      -db docadm -trig triggers -H sona01 -S 19002 -N TCP -ld docadm 
      -db dochelp -trig triggers -H sona01 -S 19003 -N TCP -ld dochelp 
      -yy 1920 -rereadnolock -T /tmp -c 30 -d mdy -Bt 350 -D 100 -mmax 8192 -nb 200 -s 160 -noshvarfix -inp 32000 
      -cpinternal utf-8 -cpstream utf-8 -cpcoll ICU-UCA
```

A `s///` cannot contain a newline (except if preceded by `\`). A solution would be to remove the newlines with `tr -d '\n'`:

```
$ echo "$VAR3" | tr -d '\n'
-db docdb -trig triggers -H sona01 -S 19001 -N TCP -ld newyork       -db docadm -trig triggers -H sona01 -S 19002 -N TCP -ld docadm       -db dochelp -trig triggers -H sona01 -S 19003 -N TCP -ld dochelp       -yy 1920 -rereadnolock -T /tmp -c 30 -d mdy -Bt 350 -D 100 -mmax 8192 -nb 200 -s 160 -noshvarfix -inp 32000       -cpinternal utf-8 -cpstream utf-8 -cpcoll ICU-UCA
```

Now use it in sed:

```
$ sed 's|PAT|'"$(echo $VAR3 | tr -d '\n')"'|' temp2.sh > Final.sh
```